# Multi authorization with CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, facebook, openid, twitter-oauth

I have my own CodeIgniter webapp.

I want to add to my site the multi-authorization from `Facebook, Google, Twitter and OpenID sites`.
(like here - https://stackoverflow.com/users/login)

Is it possible with CodeIgniter?

P.S. I've found some extensions for CI, but they are single and there is no way to merge them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is used in Stackoverflow is called [`OpenID`](http://openid.net/). Knowing the name, you can search for OpenID+CI implementations and you'll find a couple of libraries out there, and I guess [this](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/177256/) is the latest one.

Comment: But Facebook doesn't supports OpenID :'(

Comment: @Kir: Have you tried the library I posted? here's the library's [home page](http://code.google.com/p/a3m/) and this is a [demo](https://mushmellow.gamespai.com/index.php/account/sign_in)! also here's another [library](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/RPX_Login/) using janrain

Answer (score 2):

Facebook uses oAuth2
Twitter uses oAuth
StackOverflow uses OpenID.

Merging 3 entirely different protocols is not easy work, which is why no easy solution exists. You'll have to get your hands dirty for this sadly.

The closest you'll get is:

https://github.com/elliothaughin/socialize

That is not tested and  I'm not sure if Elliot ever got around to finishing it.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Also, I've already tried this extension, it's good but works only with Facebook.

Comment: Then this is the perfect opportunity for you to get into some open source! Fork, Code, Push, ???, Profit.

Comment: I am finishing work on my new library. It will be published on GitHub soon.

Comment: @Kir so is the library finished or what? I need a similar module for getting users to sign up for my codeigniter site using google/yahoo/twitter

Comment: Nope it was never finished. Use the oauth sparks I created and have a single controller that runs all of the logic.